# How to agregate queries results from dynamic table queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

To begin I am far from being an expert and I would like to have some guidance on the following subject :

- I am trying to get a query result from several table without having the table names on the query but coming as a result of another table.

I have all the table names from 1 table :
[Tables names from U5WOMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPUx.png)

What I would like to get is something as this as a result :

[Union results from Tables stored in U5WOMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXqyS.png)

```
select description, actif, code from U5WOCO
union
select description, actif, code from u5wowo
union
select description, actif, code from U5woeq;
```

Except that I would like this result without having to put the table names in the query but rather having them dynamically from the U5WOMA table since I will not know how many tables that I would have neither their names.

I did some research and I get the feeling that the response is in dynamic SQL but I am unable to find something even close to works.

I am using Oracle database.

If you have any suggestion, tutorial or advice that could help me to move to the right direction, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: The best answer depends largely on where the results are used. Is this query run by an application that can understand ref cursors? Or is this an ad-hoc query run by users and you can give them a script to generate the query? Or does the query need to run in any SQL context as a single SQL statement? Also, will the returned columns always be the same, or will they change with the tables?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option - create a function which composes a "long" `select` statement based on contents of the `u5woma` table and uses it as a *source* for the refcursor.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from u5woco;

DESCRIPTI ACTIF            CODE
--------- ---------- ----------
MANAGER   CLARK            7782
PRESIDENT KING             7839
CLERK     MILLER           7934

SQL> select * from u5wowo;

DESCRIPTI ACTIF            CODE
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK     SMITH            7369
MANAGER   JONES            7566
ANALYST   SCOTT            7788
CLERK     ADAMS            7876
ANALYST   FORD             7902

SQL> select * from u5woeq;

DESCRIPTI ACTIF            CODE
--------- ---------- ----------
SALESMAN  ALLEN            7499
SALESMAN  WARD             7521
SALESMAN  MARTIN           7654
MANAGER   BLAKE            7698
SALESMAN  TURNER           7844
CLERK     JAMES            7900

6 rows selected.
```

The `u5woma` table that contains list of all tables involved in query:

```
SQL> select * from u5woma;

TABLE_
------
U5WOCO
U5WOWO
U5WOEQ
```

Function: in order for `union` to work, all `select` statements must return the same number of columns and they must match in datatype. Your example shows that all tables share the same column list (which simplifies the task):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_u5
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(2000);
  5    l_rc  sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select table_name from u5woma) loop
  8      l_str := l_str || ' select description, actif, code from ' || cur_r.table_name
  9                     || ' union all';
 10    end loop;
 11
 12    l_str := rtrim(l_str, ' union all');
 13    open l_rc for l_str;
 14    return l_rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_u5 from dual;

F_U5
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DESCRIPTI ACTIF            CODE
--------- ---------- ----------
MANAGER   CLARK            7782
PRESIDENT KING             7839
CLERK     MILLER           7934
CLERK     SMITH            7369
MANAGER   JONES            7566
ANALYST   SCOTT            7788
CLERK     ADAMS            7876
ANALYST   FORD             7902
SALESMAN  ALLEN            7499
SALESMAN  WARD             7521
SALESMAN  MARTIN           7654
MANAGER   BLAKE            7698
SALESMAN  TURNER           7844
CLERK     JAMES            7900

14 rows selected.


SQL>
```

---

There are other possibilities as well (for example, you could return a collection; or use a pipelined function; or ...), but the main principle remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, it is a very interesting way of managing it and it is very helpfull.

If I understand correctly all the results are stored in one variable. So as long as there is less than 2000 characters I will be fine but if there are more, it will be trunqued ?

When I call the funtion directly, I have the following result :

```
SQL> 
{<DESCRIPTION=Commande 2,ACTIF=-,CODE=1001>,<DESCRIPTION=Commande 1,ACTIF=+,CODE=1000>,<DESCRIPTION=OT 1,ACTIF=+,CODE=1000>,<DESCRIPTION=OT 2,ACTIF=-,CODE=1001>,<DESCRIPTION=Actif 1,ACTIF=+,CODE=1000>,<DESCRIPTION=Actif 2,ACTIF=-,CODE=1001>,<DESCRIPTION=Actif 3,ACTIF=+,CODE=1003>,}
SQL>
```

Since the results are all in one line I have to split them in several lines to be able to use them.
I should be able to do it when I call the function f_u5 but is it possible to store the date directly on the function in order to get as many lines as I have results ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it a little differently :

I first created a new table :

```
SQL>
 create table SG_u5woma(description varchar2(80), actif varchar2(1), code varchar2(30));
SQL>
```

Then a stored procedure :

```
SQL>
create or replace procedure P_u5
  as
   begin
   delete from SG_u5woma;
     for cur_r in (select table_name from u5woma) loop
      
                      
     execute immediate 'insert into SG_u5woma (description, actif,code) select description, actif, code from ' || cur_r.table_name ;
     end loop;
 
   end;
   /
SQL>
```

The I execute the procedure :

```
SQL>
 exec P_u5();
SQL>
```

And the result is the data in the table :

```
SQL>
 select * from SG_u5woma;

Commande 2  -   1001
Commande 2  +   1003
Commande 1  +   1000
OT 1    +   1000
OT 2    -   1001
Actif 1 +   1000
Actif 2 -   1001
Actif 3 +   1003
SQL>
```

Anyway, thank you for the help, it was very helpfull.